# Populating the Tableview from the Core Data

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data

I have performed the save operation in core data and it is successfully done .It stores the data .I have also fetched the data into the log. This is my code for fetching data in log but I dont know how to fetch this data in TableView.

```
 NSError *error;


DemoAppCoreDataAppDelegate *appdelegate = (DemoAppCoreDataAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appdelegate managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName: @"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSArray *fetchedobject = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
tablearray  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:fetchedobject copyItems:YES];


for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedobject ) {

    NSLog(@ "%@",[info valueForKey:@"name"] );
}

[fetchRequest release];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend to use a `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Apple provides complete sample code in the [`NSFetchedResultsController` documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

The `NSFetchedResultsController` is specifically designed to work in between a tableView and Core Data. It makes everything a lot easier.
For example it will automatically insert and delete rows when you add or remove objects from the core data. For this you have to implement the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol. The full sample code for this is in the [protocol documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate)

Answer (score 1):

Use `fetchedobject` as `dataSource` to the tableView.

After `[fetchRequest release];` , set the delegate and datasource for the tableView programatically.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in this case is to inspect some working example I think. Look at the apple's example project Recipies, good one btw: easy and gives a good picture of how the things with CoreData and tableViews should be done:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008913